# Fullcalendar adds an extra day when using Unix time

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar, unix-timestamp

I am using fullcalendar jquery plugin. I am passing it start and end time in UNIX time. In the example below the difference between start and end is exactly 7 days. If converted into datetime it is 17 October 00:00:00 GMT and 24 October 00:00:00 GMT respectively. What I see in the fullcalendar is 8 days. Even if I take away 1 second from the end date, resulting in 23 October 23:59:59 GMT it still shows 8 days.

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    editable: true,
    allDayDefault: true,
    ignoreTimezone: true,
    firstDay: 1,
    events: function (start, end, callback) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "sample url",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                if (data != null) {
                    var events = [];
                    $(data).each(function (key, value) {
                        events.push({
                            title: value['title'],
                            start: value['start'],
                            end: value['end']
                        });
                    });
                }
                callback(events);
            }
        });
    }
```

What is the issue here? I would assume it's how fullcalendar works, but I do not see any option to change it's functionality to work as required.

Comment: Try debugging it by writing the event start and end to the console. Convert the incoming timestamps into dates as well to check that the UNIX timestamp values end up as the correct real dates.

Comment: I am getting expected values in the success handler, but for some reason they are printed twice (success handler). No idea why or if it should cause an issue. Don't know how to check if unix times are translated correctly into dates, is there fullcalendar method to check?

Comment: No but theres a perfectly good Date class which accepts Unix timestamps in the constructor....

Comment: I think it may be the duplication issue, "$('#calendar').fullCalendar" gets called twice, despite the url only getting called once, I am stumped how this can happen.